# Secure the body of a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am currently developing a website. 
At html I would like to fix the body, ie it does not move the mouse scrolling .

Comment: Why do you want to do that?  What if somebody views the site in a very small browser window?  If scrolling is not permitted, how would they be able to see the whole of the page?

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: Are you doing something like having an automatic scroller in JS or something? I know there are a lot of reasons to do a lot of ab-normal things for a specific website to function properly but I can't work out why would you want to restrict the view of the website user so much? There are so many ways to do different things, why don't you tell us what you want to achieve and we may be able to give you an idea of how to achieve it? By the way, if it is not possible to see any legal disclaimers (like a copyright statement) on the page they probably cannot be enforced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you want to do this, but this CSS should work.

```
body {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Of course, you'll need to make sure that all the content is visible in the user's viewport, which is very difficult if not impossible.

I don't recommend this.

Answer (score 1):

```
body { position:fixed; left:0; top:0; overflow:hidden; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a style to the body:

```
<body style="position: fixed;">
</body>
```